# How to get parentlist of a lookup column in CSOM

Tags: lookup-column, csom

What I want is this

```
using (Web web = lookup.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.OpenWeb(lookup.LookupWebId))
            {
                List list = lookup.r.LookupWebId.LookupList;
                Field field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(lookup.LookupField);
```

but the above is implemented in 2010, I need the Parent list of Look Up column using CSOM for SharePoint Online

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to get the Parent List information from the Lookup field from SharePoint online,

```
private static void getParentListfromLookupField(string siteURL, string strListName, string fieldInternalName, string strUserName, string strPassword)
{
    try
    {

        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteURL);
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in strPassword)
        {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(strUserName, securePassword);
        ctx.Credentials = credentials;

        Web web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(strListName);

        Field fld = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldInternalName);

        ctx.Load(fld);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        string field_schemaXml = fld.SchemaXml;

        var lookupListId = XElement.Parse(fld.SchemaXml).Attributes().First(s => s.Name == "List").Value;
        List parentList = web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(lookupListId));

        ctx.Load(parentList);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(parentList.Title);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark it as answer, if this answer helped you because it might help someone in future too :) –